# R extract unit of measure and attached number from string given list of units of measures

Tags: r, substring

I'm using R and I've got two character vectors:

```
measures <- c('cm', 'mm', 'ml')
strings <- c('hgtrdhg cm12 mhjgf','asdfsf 12mm jhgjhg','adadf 45ml','ml89 jygjgh', 'cm 59 gfhgfd')
```

I have to extract for each string the unit of measure and the associated number like:

cm12, 12mm, 45ml, ml89, cm59
(there was originally a space between cm and 59 in the last string)

the number can be either in front or after the unit of measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over the 'measures' and extract the elements

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
measures %>%
       map(~ str_extract(strings, paste0("\\d*", .x, "\\s*\\d*"))) %>%
    do.call(coalesce, .) %>%
    str_replace_all(" ", "")
#[1] "cm12" "12mm" "45ml" "ml89" "cm59"
```

---

Or if we want to use all the 'measures' at once, then `paste` it by `collapse` ing with `|`

```
pat <- paste0("(", paste("\\d*", measures, "\\s*\\d*", sep="", collapse="|"), ")")
str_replace_all(str_extract(strings, pat), " ", "")
#[1] "cm12" "12mm" "45ml" "ml89" "cm59"
```

Answer (score 1):

using base r:

```
m=paste0(".*?(\\d+\\s*(",m<-paste0(measures,collapse = "|"),")|(",m,")\\s*\\d+).*")
> sub(m,"\\1",strings)
[1] "cm12"  "12mm"  "45ml"  "ml89"  "cm 59"

sub(".*?(\\d+\\s*(cm|mm|ml)|(cm|mm|ml)\\s*\\d+).*","\\1",strings)
   [1] "cm12"  "12mm"  "45ml"  "ml89"  "cm 59"
```